# SencilJS updating array

Tags: arrays, stenciljs, tsx, stencil-component

I want to create component with table which have add, update, delete operations.
But when I try to add some test element to array I got this error

Uncaught TypeError: this.documents is not iterable at HTMLButtonElement.addNewDocument

This is simple code, but I can't figure where is bug.

```
@State()
documents: string[] = [];

addNewDocument() {
 this.documents= [... this.documents, "test2"];
}

render() {

   return (
      <Host>
          <button onClick={this.addNewDocument} type="button" class="btn btn-success">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            <span class="btn-text">add new</span>
          </button>

          {this.documents && this.documents.length ? (

            <div>

              <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {this.documents.map(document => (
                    <tr>
                      <td>{document}</td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>

            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>Loading...</div>
          )}

        </div>
      </Host>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the context (i.e. the value of `this`).

Because of how you attach the event handler (`onClick={this.addNewDocument}`) the `this` keyword within `addNewDocument` will refer to the button element, not your component instance.

Basically it's equivalent to `button.addEventListener(function() { this.documents = [ ...this.documents, "test2"] }` which would throw the same error.

There are two ways of preventing this:

**1. Arrow function**

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) inherit the context from the parent:

```
<button onClick={() => this.addNewDocument()}></button>
```

**2. Bind**

You can [manually set the context using `.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
<button onClick={this.addNewDocument.bind(this)}></button>
```